# React - child component not updating when receiving new props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to create a dot page indicator component in react. I first created a dot component, then the actual indicator component . But I have a problem with it.

The state of the indicator component depends on the props that it receives and it as well has to set the state of the individual dots passing down props. To update the state when new props come in I've used `componentWillReceiveProps`

```
class PageIndicator extends React.Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    let pills = [];
    for(var i = 0;i<props.size;i++) //Create an array of all the pills required to create the page indicator
        if(i == this.props.activeIndice) //Check which of the pills is the active one - active is true
            pills.push(<PageIndicatorPill key={i} active={true}/>);
        else
            pills.push(<PageIndicatorPill key={i} active={false}/>);

    this.state = {pills:pills};
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    let pills = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < nextProps.size; i++) //Update the indicator
        if (i == nextProps.activeIndice) //Check which of the pills is the active one - active is true
            pills.push(<PageIndicatorPill key={i} active={true} />);
        else
            pills.push(<PageIndicatorPill key={i} active={false} />);

    this.setState({ pills: pills });
}
```

And here is the dot component

```
class PageIndicatorPill extends React.Component{


    constructor(props){

        super(props);
        if(this.props.active)
            this.state={image : onState};
        else
            this.state = { image: offState };

        this.style = {
            backgroundImage:`url(${this.state.image})`,
            marginRight:'10px', 
            height:"32px", 
            width:"32px" ,
            display:"inline-block"};

    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        if (nextProps.active)
            this.setState({ image: onState });
        else
            this.setState({image : offState});
    }
```

If I go ahead and console log the states, they update, but the problem is that the component doesn't seem to re-render accordingly and I can't figure out why. Can you help me out please?

Comment: store data in state not components

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean

Comment: You should render `<PageIndicatorPill />`(s) using state data - construction like `pills.push(<PageIndicatorPill />...)` can be used from `render` (or inside rendering methods called from `render`) but components shouldn't be stored in state, it'll hurt you in the future

Comment: Steve just gave you an example ;) You can use `shouldComponentUpdate` to force `render` on updated props - no need to copy props to state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your state is updating, however you only set your styles in the constructor of your `PageIndicatorPill` component. `this.style` would need to be updated within the `componentWillReceiveProps` method.

However.. This can be simplified a lot from the example you have provided. There is no need to mirror the active prop in state as `image`. You could do something like:

```
class PageIndicatorPill extends React.Component{

  getStyle() {
    const { active } = this.props;
    return {
        backgroundImage: `url(${active ? onState : offState})`,
        marginRight: '10px', 
        height: '32px', 
        width: '32px',
        display: 'inline-block'
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={this.getStyle()} />
    );
  }
}
```

You didn't post a render function so this example is just a simple demonstration of using props directly to get the styles, but hopefully the above makes sense.

Your other component can also be simplified and not need state...

```
class PageIndicator extends React.Component{

  getPills() {
    const { size, activeIndice } = this.props;
    let pills = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      pills.push(
        <PageIndicatorPill key={i} active={i === activeIndice} />
      );
    }
    return pills;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.getPills()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: :facepalm: Thank you so much,I haven't even realized that I wasn't updating the graphics. And yes,that simplification is useful.

Comment: Just updated with a further simplification to your main component. Hope that also helps